# Create Timeline android app

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android app and i'd like to include a timeline like the one in facebook
it'll have a vertical scrollbar to view the whole Timeline events till the end
Here is a sample photo I made

[image: Screenshot]

I know the android basics, and I've made some simple apps before
but i'm missing the way to mix that graphical line with the texts, and to extend this line till the bottom of the layout.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to do this the old fashioned way-  custom view and draw it yourself to the canvas with drawText and drawLine commands.

Comment: I searched for the Custom View, and how to draw to the canvas
but i didn't found something to help me for what i need..
i'm still a beginner android developer, so if you can provide a tutorial link to teach me the Custom View or the Specific part i need, it'll be much appreciated
Thanks anyway